# correct java syntax for generics with extends

Tags: java, generics, syntax

this is a piece of code i'm struggling with.

```
public class Channel<T extends Something>{
   public Channel(){}
   public void method(T something){}
}

public class Manager{
   private static ArrayList<Channel<? extends Something>> channels
         = new ArrayList<Channel<? extends Something>>();
   public static <T extends Something> void OtherMethod(T foo){
      for(Channel<? extends Something> c : channels)
        c.method(foo);  // this does not work
   }
}
```

The line that does not work gives me compiler error:

```
The method method(capture#1-of ? extends Something) in the type Channel<capture#1-of ? extends Something> is not applicable for the arguments (T)
```

I don't understand this error. If I remove all the generics in Manager class it is working but type unsafe.
How should I do this in correct Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a type parameter for your method `public <T extends Something> void method(T foo)`

```
public class Channel<T extends Something> {
  public Channel() {
  }

  public <T extends Something> void method(T foo) {
  }
}

public class Manager {
   private static ArrayList<Channel<? extends Something>> channels = new ArrayList<Channel<? extends Something>>();

   public static <T extends Something> void OtherMethod(T foo) {
     for (Channel<? extends Something> c : channels)
        c.method(foo); // this does not work
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's inherently unsafe.

What happens if you add a `Channel<MyThing>` to the list, then call `OtherMethod()` with a `YourThing`?

You should make the entire class generic (and make the members non-static), and use the same `T` for the channels and the parameter.

Comment: Never happens. I simplified the code. OtherMethod would search in his channels for a Channel<YourThing> and would use this. Please don't tell me that my code is not ellegant. Please tell me why it is not correct.

Comment: @ArcticLord: The way your code is written, that is not true.  If you aren't showing your actual code, I can't help you.